# function to add a div inside submenu in genesis framework

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking to find a way to add a new div with a class inside submenu in genesis framework using any genesis hook or php function.

Here is the example:

**Original Code:**

```
<div class="nav">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary">
   <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">Menu Item 1</li>
   <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">Menu Item 2</li>
      <ul class=submenu>
         <li id="menu-item-111">Menu Item 1</li>
         <li id="menu-item-112">Menu Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**What I want to Achieve:**

```
<div class="nav">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary">
   <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">Menu Item 1</li>
   <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">Menu Item 2</li>
      <ul class=submenu>
         <li id="menu-item-111">Menu Item 1</li>
         <li id="menu-item-112">Menu Item 2</li>
         <div class="nmd"> Some text or images here</div>
      </ul>
    <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would probably be better to contain the div in `<li>` tags if you're going to be putting it inside a list.

Comment: @gaynorvader Please check the 3rd item (Jelly Town) on navigation menu in  http://174.120.233.154/~a348/nextmktg/jle/ 
You will get an idea why I want to use under ul in sub menu and not li

Comment: @Dolours do you have an easy solution of jquery for genesis framework?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that can be done, but you could try writing your own custom walker class: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

You could also create a new blank menu item (in the dashboard), and give it the class of "nmd": http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Comment: actually its not just about styling or giving a class name I need to add a div. At the moment I am using the following which adds the desired content under menu class but I don't know how to add it under sub menu.

Comment: add_filter( 'genesis_nav_items', 'custom_sbmenu', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'custom_sbmenu', 10, 2 );
function custom_sbmenu($menu, $args) {
$args = (array)$args;
if ( 'primary' !== $args['theme_location'] )
return $menu;
$follow = '<div class="sbclass">Our Jelly Town cat that loves
climbing from tree to tree!
Learn how to make Cheeseball with our art supplies and creative craft ideas.
<a class="cheesebtn">View Cheeseball Kit</a>
</div>';
return $menu . $follow;
}